# Exclude specific users from Apache authentication

Tags: apache, authentication

I have an `AuthType` directive in my apache `sites-enabled` directory which allows all valid-users using `Require valid-user`.  I'm at a point where I need to restrict access by blacklisting/excluding specific users; is there a way to do this without doing `Require` on the inverse (e.g. `Require` on a group that contains everyone else except for the specific users to blacklist)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK the only thing you could do is altering your

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/user/file
Require valid-user
```

Where valid-user means a user with a validated password For a:

```
AuthUserFile /path/to/user/file
AuthGroupFile /path/to/group/file
Require group mygroup
Satisfy All
```

Then you would have to maintain a group file with the authorized users inside. There is nothing to say "**any valid-user but not in this group**" only "**any valid-user which is also in this group**" (details [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html#lettingmorethanonepersonin))